# SQL Group by query - choose row in priority

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in Oracle database, where I need create query for following table (result of query).

```
CUSTOMER_REFENRECE LQ   UN   SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS
------------------ ---- ---- --------------------------------
FI020098           null null Not Restricted as per ADR SP 375
FI020098           HZ   1219 HZ UN1219
FI020098           LQ   1219 UN1219
FI020097           null null null
FI020097           LQ   1219 UN1219
```

I need get just one row per `CUSTOMER_REFERENCE` in order to:

**HZ > LQ > NULL**

**If there is one HZ, then just return HZ row (skip null)**

```
FI020098 - HZ- 1219- HZ UN1219
```

**If there isnt any HZ and at least one LQ, return row with LQ**

```
FI020097 - LQ - 1219 - UN1219
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYyMH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and map the `LQ` values to numbers in order of sort importance using `DECODE()` (or `CASE`):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY customer_reference
           ORDER BY DECODE( LQ, 'HZ', 1, 'LQ', 2, 3 ) ASC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```